# Powershell shortcut for launching frequently-used applications

Tags: powershell, shortcuts, portable-apps

There is probably a few dozen apps that I use on a daily basis.  These are apps that are not 'installed' but reside somewhere in the file system.  Launching any one of them involves something like this:

```
e:
cd \PortableApps\FileZillaPortable
FileZillaPortable.exe
```

(No, not all of them are 'portableapps' so using the portable apps launcher does not solve the problem.  I do, however, tend to stick them in the PortableApps folder.)
I'd like to make a quicker way to access these.  I could put a ton of batch files somewhere in the path but.. What a mess!

Since I'm constantly using a powershell window, I thought it would be nice to have a shortcut that would launch my apps.

How can I make a single nice shortcut that works for all such apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following script to my profile.  Now all I need to do at a powershell prompt is type `p` `(space)` `(ctrl-space)` and start typing the application name.  Or I can type `p -AppName`. (completer appears after pressing spacebar)  Note that you don't have to enter the complete name; the `p` script will open the first app whose name matches your value.

[image: Example of completer]

(Incidentally, I used LICECap to make the animated GIF.)

This is my first pass at this.  Any suggestions for improvement would be appreciated.

For your use, you will just need to add your paths to the approots array.

```
$Global:approots = @(
"E:\PortableApps",
($env:USERPROFILE+"\Downloads")
)
if (-not (Test-Path ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt"))) {
    $approots | %{
        $approot = $_
        dir -Recurse ($approot+"\*.exe") | 
        %{ $_.Name.Remove($_.Name.LastIndexOf(".")) + "`t" + $_.FullName } 
    } |
    sort | Out-File -FilePath ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt")
}    
function global:p {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS 
    Launch a portable app.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Launches a portable app whose name starts with the supplied parameter.
    .EXAMPLE
    p filezil
    .PARAMETER PartialFileName
    The beginning of the name of a portable app's EXE file
    #>    
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param($AppName="start.exe")

    process {
        if (-not (Test-Path ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt"))) {
            $approots | %{
                $approot = $_
                dir -Recurse ($approot+"\*.exe") | 
                %{ $_.Name.Remove($_.Name.LastIndexOf(".")) + "`t" + $_.FullName } 
            } |
            sort | Out-File -FilePath ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt")
        }    
        gc ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt") | ?{ $_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf("`t")).StartsWith($AppName) }|
        select -first 1 | %{ start ($_.SubString($_.IndexOf("`t")+1)) }
    }
}
Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName 'p' -ParameterName 'AppName' -ScriptBlock {
    # learned this from icklicksick on https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/5nqw4m/adding_tabcompletion_to_your_powershell_functions/
    param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParameter)
    gc ($PSScriptRoot+"\AppShortcuts.txt") | %{$val=$_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf("`t"));[System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($val, $val, 'ParameterValue', $val)}
}
```

The gist of this code is to create a text file that contains a list of app names and their full paths. (tab delimited) Then the `p` function allows you to search for apps whose name starts with the `AppName` parameter.  Then we use `Register-ArgumentCompleter` to add all of the app names to the list of possible values for `AppName`.

Answer (score 0):

Back in DOS 3.2 days I made batch files to create shortcuts. I had a whole folder of them and then I put that folder in my PATH variable so that I could run them, like commands, from anywhere.

In LINUX people often dump all of their binaries in a `/usr/bin` folder and put that in the PATH variable. The equivalent in Windows would be using something like:

> %userprofile%\bin\

Put that in your PATH. Then dump all your binaries in there. (I know that sounds messy but it would be super easy)

Comment: I, too, have used that approach.  Having all EXEs in one folder would not be practical with most modern apps.  Having BAT/CMD files in one folder (in the `path`) would work but requires creation of another batch file each time you add a program.  Of course, so does my method, so maybe it would make sense to rebuild the appshortcuts.txt file every once in a while.  Or schedule a job to rebuild it when new files are detected in the specified paths.  I think I'll add the latter.

Comment: By 'so does my method', I meant it requires you to do something extra each time you add a program.  In my case you must delete and recreate the appshortcuts.txt file.

Comment: I agree. The benefit of discrete files is flexibility of command name. instead of "p <command>" sometimes you really do want to have a custom name you can type like just "scan" instead of "p netscan". There is too much overhead in making batch files, that's why I don't do it anymore. I remember TUI shell programs that were just app launchers, back in the day.

Comment: You can edit the 'alias' in the appshortcuts.txt file to be anything you like.  Each line contains the name that appears in autocomplete, and (after a single `tab`) the fill path to the executable.